# Realm and unique objects

Tags: android, unique-constraint, realm

I've recently started to play around with Realm for Android, but I can't seem to find any information about whether it's possible to set a unique constraint on a `RealmObject`, as to avoid duplicates.

I'm appending data to an implementation of the `RealmBaseAdapter` and I don't want duplicates.

Is this something that can't be achieved by adding an annotation or something to my `RealmObject` or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christian from Realm here.
A RealmBaseAdapter is normally just used to show data you give it, so any restrictions on input data must be made by you.

That said, we are working hard on implementing primary key support which will ensure uniqueness when inserting data into Realm, which then can be queried and added to an adapter. You can follow the the work-in-progress in this pull request here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/565. We are hoping to release it in the next update.

Comment: Ok, so basically what I should do is apply a filter to the `Adapter`? What about duplicates in the `Realm`? If I call `Realm.createObject` and then select all items that look the same (`equalTo("name")`) for instance, then I can remove all items, except for one or what would you recommend?

Comment: As you probably know your data before inserting them, I would try to lookup the object and edit it instead of inserting a new one and then deleting the duplicate.